# Downloading fails at random for our users from Amazon S3, need help figuring out what's wrong

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3

We have a file sharing service where users can upload, share and download their files. We are using Amazon S3 to store our files.

We're facing an issue where small files download fine, but when files are bigger than 1 GB, the downloading drops/fails after some time, and it's completely random. Mostly it happens when there is a high downloading activity by our users during office working hours. The error users see when downloading drops is **"Failed - Network error"**.

When user downloads any file we do some preprocessing on that download, for example, we record the downloaded file, save analytics data, record the bandwidth, etc. Later we download the file straight from S3 URL.

Code to download the file is:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="FILENAME.EXT"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header('X-Accel-Redirect: ' . rawurlencode(  S3_FILEPATH  ) );
```

Here `S3_FILEPATH` is a url like `/s3/ PATH_TO_FILE ? QUERY_STRING`

That URL passes to nginx proxy settings are:

```
location ~* ^/s3/(.*) {
  proxy_http_version      1.1;

  proxy_set_header        Authorization '';
  proxy_set_header        Connection "";

  proxy_pass_header       X-Access;
  proxy_hide_header       x-amz-id-2;
  proxy_hide_header       x-amz-request-id;
  proxy_hide_header       x-amz-server-side-encryption;
  proxy_hide_header       x-amz-meta-server-side-encryption;
  proxy_hide_header       x-amz-meta-lastmodifieddate;
  proxy_hide_header       x-amz-meta-size;
  proxy_hide_header       x-amz-meta-type;
  proxy_hide_header       Set-Cookie;
  proxy_ignore_headers    "Set-Cookie";

  resolver                10.0.0.2 valid=300s;
  resolver_timeout        10s;

  proxy_buffering         off;
  proxy_intercept_errors  on;

  proxy_pass              http://s3.amazonaws.com/$1;
}
```

I cannot seem to figure out why this drop in downloading happens. What am I doing wrong? What should I do to make the downloading reliable? I found help related to configuration, but found nothing on how to make downloading reliable.

I will be very grateful if the community can help me figure out why this is happening and what I can do to fix it.

Comment: Anything in your nginx error logs? What about in your php error logs? It's not unreasonable that for a 1GB download over an unreliable connection that you're going to get lots of failures.

Comment: Nothing in Nginx or PHP logs

Comment: Serve directly from S3 (and optionally CloudFront). And consider file compression.

Answer (score 0):

Please, stop distributing Amazon S3 objects via your server.

Use Amazon CloudFront and signed URLs if you need protect these objects.

Network error happens all the time, but your server can't reconnect and repeat downloading. The user's browser can do this by default.